# Problem with arguments of newcommand in node options

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

I have defined a new command in which there are 7 arguments. Three of them are some options for "node". Since these arguments include some options for "node", I have defined two other new commands consisting of those options. But when I want to compile the file, It does not compile! 
Could you please help me with correcting my mistakes in the code!
Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[border= 5 pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{times,comment}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgflibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.callouts}

\newcommand{\level}[7]{
\draw [purple] ( 3.1 , #2  ) -- ( 3.6 , #2  ) node[ #3 ]{ \tiny #2  }; 
\draw [black,densely dotted] ( 3.6 , #2  )  -- ( 3.9 , #4  ); 
\draw [black] ( 3.9 , #4  ) node [red, #5]{\tiny  #1}  -- ( 4.9 , #4  ) node[ #5 ]{ \tiny #4  }; 
\draw [black,densely dotted] ( 4.9 , #4  )  -- ( 5.2 , #6  ); 
\draw [blue] ( 5.2 , #6  )  -- ( 5.7 , #6  ) node[ #7]{\tiny  #6 }; 
}


\newcommand{\ab}{above, midway, yshift=-3,  xshift=6}
\newcommand{\be}{below, midway, yshift= 3,  xshift=6}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\level{$ 2 $}{2.176}{\ab}{2.541}{\ab}{2.176}{\ab}
\level{$ 3 $}{3.767}{\be}{3.808}{\be}{3.676}{\be}
\level{$ 4 $}{3.947}{\ab}{4.134}{\ab}{3.947}{\ab}
\level{$ 5 $}{5.804}{\be}{5.631}{\be}{5.804}{\be}
\level{$ 6 $}{6.047}{\ab}{5.879}{\ab}{6.048}{\ab}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `,font=\tiny` in the node options instead of `\tiny #2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure it's the expected output, but using styles doesn't raise errors:

```
\documentclass[border= 5 pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{times,comment}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgflibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.callouts}

\newcommand{\level}[7]{
\draw [purple] ( 3.1 , #2  ) -- ( 3.6 , #2  ) node[ #3 ]{ \tiny #2  }; 
\draw [black,densely dotted] ( 3.6 , #2  )  -- ( 3.9 , #4  ); 
\draw [black] ( 3.9 , #4  ) node [red, #5]{\tiny  #1}  -- ( 4.9 , #4  ) node[ #5 ]{ \tiny #4  }; 
\draw [black,densely dotted] ( 4.9 , #4  )  -- ( 5.2 , #6  ); 
\draw [blue] ( 5.2 , #6  )  -- ( 5.7 , #6  ) node[ #7]{\tiny  #6 }; 
}


\tikzset{
  ab/.style={above, yshift=-3,  xshift=6},
  be/.style={below, yshift= 3,  xshift=6},
}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\level{$ 2 $}{2.176}{ab}{2.541}{ab}{2.176}{ab}
\level{$ 3 $}{3.767}{be}{3.808}{be}{3.676}{be}
\level{$ 4 $}{3.947}{ab}{4.134}{ab}{3.947}{ab}
\level{$ 5 $}{5.804}{be}{5.631}{be}{5.804}{be}
\level{$ 6 $}{6.047}{ab}{5.879}{ab}{6.048}{ab}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: dear egreg, it does not work completely. But it was a smart suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Ti*k*Zy way of defining the styles.

```
\documentclass[border= 5 pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{times,comment}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgflibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.callouts}

\newcommand{\level}[7]{
\draw [purple] ( 3.1 , #2  ) -- ( 3.6 , #2  ) node[ #3 ]{ \tiny #2  }; 
\draw [black,densely dotted] ( 3.6 , #2  )  -- ( 3.9 , #4  ); 
\draw [black] ( 3.9 , #4  ) node [red, #5]{\tiny  #1}  -- ( 4.9 , #4  ) node[ #5 ]{ \tiny #4  }; 
\draw [black,densely dotted] ( 4.9 , #4  )  -- ( 5.2 , #6  ); 
\draw [blue] ( 5.2 , #6  )  -- ( 5.7 , #6  ) node[ #7]{\tiny  #6 }; 
}


\tikzset{ab/.style={above, midway, yshift=-3,  xshift=6},
be/.style={below, midway, yshift= 3,  xshift=6}}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\level{$ 2 $}{2.176}{ab}{2.541}{ab}{2.176}{ab}
\level{$ 3 $}{3.767}{be}{3.808}{be}{3.676}{be}
\level{$ 4 $}{3.947}{ab}{4.134}{ab}{3.947}{ab}
\level{$ 5 $}{5.804}{be}{5.631}{be}{5.804}{be}
\level{$ 6 $}{6.047}{ab}{5.879}{ab}{6.048}{ab}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]